# eclipse-slow building workspace after build path changes

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine, workspace

I working on some projects that references to one game library called "AndEngine"

The AndEngine library linked as a reference to all of this projects
so far so good.

But now,after i add one of this projects to the Andengine library build path(because i need to import one class)-the eclipse buildng workspace take life time.

Before i did it,all run good and quickly.i cant work in that way,and i don't want to add all my classes to the Andengine library.

Any idea?

Comment: did it twice.i suspect that the reason is the fact that all the other project building again when i linked one of them to the big library-so they all linked now somehow.

Comment: prior that,they all was depend on one library-not that library depend on another one of them-so maybe i increase to building workspace time dramatically